# Why do I have Signing Error: error:02001002 in PHPmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Facing here a weird issue using `PHPmailer`.
I have several scripts sending emails everyday with certified sender signature but...

A brand new php page makes signature fails. When I remove the `$mail->sign` the email got sent with no further error

All email files are in from the same folder.

> Warning: tempnam(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is
> not within the allowed path(s):
> (/home/uploads_tmp:/home/php-scripts:/home/clients/cineferte.fr/http)
> in /home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 2892
>
> Warning: tempnam(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is
> not within the allowed path(s):
> (/home/uploads_tmp:/home/php-scripts:/home/clients/cineferte.fr/http)
> in /home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 2893
>
> Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in
> /home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 2894
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' with
> message 'Signing Error: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such
> file or directory' in
> /home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php:2927
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1568):
> PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->createBody() #1
> /home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1464):
> PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->preSend() #2
> /home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/test.php(62):
> PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #3 {main} thrown in
> /home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 2927

Any clue ?

Thanks

EDIT :
Why do other pages using the same script work fine ???

Here is the code...
.KEY, .PEM and .PEM are in the same folder called 'mail'

```
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
// use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\POP3;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'autoload.php';
// $pop = POP3::popBeforeSmtp('pop3.cineferte.fr', 110, 30, $user, $mdp, 1);
//Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER; 
    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.cineferte.fr'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
    $mail->Username   = 'user'; 
    $mail->Password   = 'password'; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS ;
    $mail->Port       = 465; 

//Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@cineferte.fr', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('to@cineferte.fr', 'Joe User');

//Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    
//  DKIM
    $mail->DKIM_domain = 'cineferte.fr' ;
    $mail->DKIM_private = 'mail/dkim.private';
    $mail->DKIM_selector = 'selector' ;
    $mail->DKIM_passphrase = '';
    $mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From ;
    $mail->DKIM_copyHeaderFields = true;
    $mail->DKIM_extraHeaders = ['List-Unsubscribe', 'List-Help'];

    $mail->sign(    'mail/gp.crt', 'mail/gp.key', 'xxxxxxx', 'mail/gp.pem' );
        
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
```

Comment: `'Signing Error: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory` Looks like a component is missing. Is openssl installed?

Comment: Looks like you have a permissions or ownership problem.

Comment: @MarkusZeller

OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.2u 20 Dec 2019
OpenSSL Header Version OpenSSL 1.0.2l 25 May 2017
Openssl default config /usr/local/openssl/openssl.cnf

openssl.cafile /usr/local/openssl/cacert.pem
openssl.capath no value

Comment: @Synchro : why some work and this one does not ? Should I renew the certificates ?

Comment: It’s not a validity problem, it’s that either the files don’t exist or they are unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my issue by changing few things in the `PHPMailer.php` after I figured out the result seems to be dependent from which folder the variables come from

#2888 & 2889

```
$file = tempnam($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_folder', 'srcsign');
$signed = tempnam($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_folder', 'mailsign');
```

I also had to add `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].` in front of each of the signing files `.CRT, .PEM, .KEY` as well as `DKIM`